# JMH Timeout doesn't interrupt

Tags: java, jmh

While trying to work with timeouts in JMH, I found that none of the timeouts actually caused any interrupts. I can reduce the problem to the following few lines:

```
package main.java;

import org.openjdk.jmh.Main;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TimeoutBenchmark {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, RunnerException {
        Main.main(args);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @Warmup(iterations = 0)
    @Timeout(time = 10, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public long benchmark() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Since `Thread.sleep` handles interrupts, I would expect each iteration to run 10 seconds, as opposed to 20 seconds. However, this is not the case:

```
# JMH version: 1.20
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0_144, VM 25.144-b01
# VM invoker: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\java.exe
# VM options: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# Warmup: <none>
# Measurement: 20 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 s per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Average time, time/op
# Benchmark: main.java.TimeoutBenchmark.benchmark

# Run progress: 0,00% complete, ETA 00:03:20
# Fork: 1 of 10
Iteration   1: 20,004 s/op
Iteration   2: 20,009 s/op
Iteration   3: 20,009 s/op
Iteration   4: 20,014 s/op
Iteration   5: 20,003 s/op
Iteration   6: 20,003 s/op
Iteration   7: 20,003 s/op
```

Why is that? How can this code be changed such that each iteration actually interrupts after 10 seconds?

Comment: interesting, I found that http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jmh-dev/2015-May/001912.html , however that still says there should be an interrupt, at least. Tried with different versions and it doesn't work in all of them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `BenchmarkHandler` there is a comment in code when handling timeouts

> ```
>     // now we communicate all worker threads should stop
>     control.announceDone();
>
>     // wait for all workers to transit to teardown
>     control.awaitWarmdownReady();
>
>     // Wait for the result, handling timeouts
>     while (completed.size() < numThreads) {
> ```

so basically this Timeout works only for `teardown` phase.

However I think that javadoc for this annotation should be amended with this information.

Teardown is described here: http://java-performance.info/jmh/

Also this mail can be useful: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jmh-dev/2015-May/001912.html

Comment: Might be a bug though. If you change the order in which these methods are called (timeout check and `awaitWarmdownReady()`), timeout works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your info! As suggested by @Cargeh, changing the order of the method calls did the trick. I changed the order and patched the jmh jar.